# Show that the groups are homomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

T={the n-th roots of unity} is a cyclic group of order n with the multiplication as operation. How can I show that there is a group homomorphism between this group and  $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ ?? Do I have to find a function such that f(a*b)=f(a)+f(b)?? How can I find such a function??

Comment: How do you define "homomorphic"?

Comment: f:G1 -> G2 is a group homomorphism if f(a*b)=f(a)°f(b), where a and b are in G1,* is the operation of G1 and ° is the operation of G2.

Comment: Yes, I know what a group homomorphism is. But what does it mean for two groups to be homomorphic?

Comment: I edited by post...

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups. Then the trivial map
$$
\phi: e_G \mapsto e_H
$$
is a homomorphism between the two groups. ($e_H$ and $e_G$ are the neutral elements in the groups.)